# How can i get points on map that are within a certain radius

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm using google maps API v2 for android. once the user opens the page I'm getting his current location and put a marker there.

Now i'd like to read a list of locations from my DB, find out which ones are in a certain radius (user defined radius) and display markers for only those points that are within range, how can i do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to check out [Location#distanceBetween(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D%29). Calculate the distance between where the user pointed and a point in the DB. If the distance is less than the radius then it is within range.